# How would I optimize this search function?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm having a tough time thinking through how I can make my search function more optimal. So I have a situation where I load an array of objects from a SQLITE database. Essentially one element in the array has multiple properties that can be accessed. Inside one element of the array, you have properties like time and rooms. I want to make the search flexible without having the user to filter what they are searching for. What I don't like about my implementation is that I filter through both time and room, then I for loop the filtered arrays and add them to a general "searchArrayToDisplay." I think the for loop is wasteful. I was wondering if there is a way I can append the filtered elements to the general "searchArrayToDisplay" without having to for loop? The method below is generally fast, but I think there's a better way that I'm just not seeing. Hopefully I am clear. Thanks for any help!

```
let filteredTime = searchArray.filter { (time: ProductModel) -> Bool in
    if time.customText1 == nil {
        return false
    } else {
        return  time.customText1.rangeOfString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }   
}
var m : ProductModel
for m in filteredTime {
    searchArrayToDisplay.append(m)
}

let filteredRooms = searchArray.filter { (session: ProductModel) -> Bool in
    if session.roomName == nil {
        return false
    } else {
        return session.roomName.rangeOfString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }   
}
for pm in filteredRooms {
    searchArrayToDisplay.append(pm)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Logical OR Operator. like this

```
let filteredTimeAndRooms = searchArray.filter { model in

    let foundTime = model.time?.rangeOfString(searchString) != nil
    let foundRoom = model.roomName?.rangeOfString(searchString) != nil

    return foundTime || foundRoom
}

searchArrayToDisplay = filteredTimeAndRooms
```

Comment: the first `model.time` should actually be `model.customText1?` and you ommited `. CaseInsensitiveSearch`

Comment: That's quite irrelevant, since nobody would just copy and paste code from the Internet without making sure it works for their purposes.

Comment: I show how it can be achieved. Nobody will just copy and paste it right ? @luk2302

Answer (score 0):

Just merge both comparisons into one and be careful when to return early:

```
let searched = searchArray.filter { (prod : ProductModel) -> Bool in
    if let room = prod.roomName {
        if room.rangeOfString(searchString, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil {
            return true
        }
    }
    if let text = prod.customText1 {
        return text.rangeOfString(searchString, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
    return false
}
```

Either you assign that directly via `searchArrayToDisplay = searchArray.filter {...}` or you append the array via `searchArrayToDisplay += searched`.

Comment: Yeah. I don't think this will work. Because each element in the array has 2 Properties time and room. So returning into one statement might miss the other property.

Comment: If that makes any sense.

Comment: @imnill It does work, I tried it - try it yourself and you will see